# Turn off GAE Task Queue Logging

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, configuration, task-queue

I am using the Java version of Google App Engine's Push Task Queue. When I build my application, the amount of logging that is spit out from task queue during the build and tests are *ridiculous*! If there was some sort of bug in my program and I had to read through the build logs to find out which test is failing, it will be very hard to find the problem test when trying to dig through endless lines of Task Queue logging. I thought the solution would have been a simple configuration, as defined in the [Java Task Queue Configuration Page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue), but I cannot find such a logging configuration.